# libVLC integration in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, vlc, libvlc

I'm using Qt Creator 5.2 and want to integrate libVLC in my own project. So I downloaded the source of libVLC (for Qt) and also the VLC player itself. I think that I have to build the libVLC source to transform into a libary. But I don't know how to do this. I see that there's a CMakeLists.txt, but as far as I know I can not use CMake to build pro file for QT Creator, but only a sln file for Microsoft VS (which I don't use). Can anybody tell me how to build libVLC?

Thank you

Comment: you shouldn't really need custom compiled libVLC just the .dll and header files shouldn't you?

Comment: Probably. But where to get them? The only compiled library I have found was for Visual Studio 2012. (http://projects.tano.si/vlc-qt)

Comment: is your question more "how do I link libvlc with a visual studio project"? https://code.google.com/p/vc-libvlc/

Answer (score 1):

1. [Qt Creator has support for CMake projects](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.8/creator-project-cmake.html)
2. You may build the library using [CMake itself](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html)
3. If you're on Linux, then your distribution likely has libvlc and its development headers built and packaged, just search for it in a software center or command-line meta-package manager like `apt` or `yum`. If you're on Windows, bad luck :) , you have to build it yourself from sources :)

Comment: Ahh I see that I can open CMakeLists.txt with Creator. I tried to run it, but I get error message "CMake Error at cmake/FindLIBVLC.cmake:90 (MESSAGE): Could not find LibVLC". Do I have to configure further parameters?

Comment: No this error means that you're trying to open a project which _depends_ on LibVLC (previously compiled and installed system-wide). You should grab source from https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/

Comment: Well :) I've just checked, the official VLC sources, including libvlc, are built using GNU autotools toolchain, you may take a look at their official source repository at http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=tree So the question is what you're trying to build, exactly, and where have you got it? :)

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. I downloaded the offical QT bindings of libVLC from http://projects.tano.si/vlc-qt. In fact, this seems not to be the libVLC SDK. ;) Ok, so where to get the real official libVLC SDK I should use? Is it part of the source of the VLC player?

Comment: Well, likely. At least [all] Linux distributions, e.g. Debian and OpenSUSE, build their libvlc packages right from VLC sources. Since you're likely on Windows you should check this page https://wiki.videolan.org/Win32Compile/

Comment: And, well, maybe you really need a pre-built library (.DLL) with the set of development headers? Actually format of DLLs and headers don't depend on your IDE but rather on the platform (Windows/Linux x86/64/Whatever) you're using.